# 1/3 octave band chart in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a 1/3 octave band chart in Excel 2007 but I don't find the way to do it. Excel only allows me to put the 'x' axis into a logarithmic one, but the scale for 1/3 octave band  is not this one.

In 1/3 octave band chart the next values must be equaly spaced in the 'x' axis:
63, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000 (Hz)

Can I do it in VBA Excel? or there is an easier way to do it?
Any suggestion please? Thank you!

Comment: In my opinion you can do it in Excel. Put your question in [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) which could be more adequate to that kind of questions. One Tip- include link to sample chart in your question there.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question, what you are looking for IS a logarithmic X-axis.

It sounds like you need every tick on the axis to double.
A logarithmic x-axis is where every tick multiplies by some value 'k' (if k = 2, it doubles).

Now all left for you to do is determine the spacing you want for the x-axis.

Sample demonstrating a chart with *logarithmix* X-axis

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but the axis it's NOT logarithmic, is 1/3 octave band like I mentioned before. You can see here an example of a chart: (http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.soundreduction.co.uk/Image/image/impactfoam_delta_lw_lowres.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.soundreduction.co.uk/Products/Soundproofing-For-Floors/Impactafoam/Acoustic-Data/&usg=__naDjx8PBVBURh50mjZkY8WFvqe0=&h=981&w=1293&sz=349&hl=ca&start=6&zoom=1&tbnid=x4nE_2kNvCPXWM:&tbnh=114&tbnw=150&ei=f5BoUfiyFJOu7AbT5YDgAw&um=1&itbs=1&sa=X&ved=0CDYQrQMwBQ).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is the following:

Create a LINE graph. Not a scatter graph. I chose the Line with marker option. If you hover your mouse over the buttons, they will tell you what they are. Then you need at least three columns. One column has the center frequencies, one column has your decibel values (assuming greater then zero but they don't have to be), and a third dummy column. I made my dummy column have values of all -1. Then you plot your data by going to select data source, and only select the column that has the decibel data and the dummy data (it only gives you one place to select, apart from two in a scatter plot). Then, in the Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels to the right of the same Select Data Window, click edit and select your center frequencies. This should produce what you need. Your dummy data will be displayed. What you can do is adjust the minimum range of your vertical axis. Since all my data was positive and I made my dummy data negative, I adjusted my minimum vertical axis to be zero, thus hiding the dummy data.
[1/3 octave plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD7S4.png)